# Laravel Policies VS Roles/Permissions Implementation

Tags: laravel-5, entrust, policies

I have implemented small test code with Laravel Policies . I am wondering whether this is the right method to implement an roles based permission system. I also used Entrust Role Permission package too. My requirement is as follows :
1. List of Roles 
2. List of Modules 
3. Each Module has set of permissions
4. Each Role linked with Set of Permissions

Policies seems to connected with Models. When we create a complex application which we group Models in to components (or services providers), this approach seems to be difficult. Kindly advice on this issue .
Thanks in advance